# Stuck in terminal setup page? (new to Linux)

Tags: linux, chrome-book

I just installed Linux on my 2018 Acer Chromebook and am stuck on a page with buttons ( Manage Linux, SSH, Terminal Settings, and Dev Settings). I'm unable to type and two buttons (Manage Linux and Dev Settings) both redirect to my Chromebook's settings page. SSH takes me to an SSH setup page and Terminal Settings is just Settings for the terminal itself. I'll provide pictures. I've tried every tutorial I could find, but none of them have seemingly had this issue. Please keep in mind that I am new to this and this could be very solvable and I just haven't found the right answers yet. Any help is appreciated.[image]

Comment: Linux is a kernel, not a complete operating system. Which distribution are you trying to install?